# Mapping a component to react-spring-3d-carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Does anyone know how to map a function to react-spring-3d-carousel? This is the code I have but nothing seems to be working. My data structure for portfolioItems is fine and ImageMedia renders one card only instead of mapping each card to its respective place.

It seems I am only able to render one car successfully, but not sure what's wrong here. Maybe if someone can look at the mapping function they'll be able to see where I'm screwing up.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Carousel from "react-spring-3d-carousel";
import { config } from "react-spring";

function Rotate(props) {
  const table = props.cards.map((element, index) => {
    return { ...element, onClick: () => setGoToSlide(index) };
  });

  const [offsetRadius, setOffsetRadius] = useState(0);
  const [showArrows, setShowArrows] = useState(false);
  const [goToSlide, setGoToSlide] = useState(null);
  const [cards] = useState(table);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOffsetRadius(props.offset);
    setShowArrows(props.showArrows);
  }, [props.offset, props.showArrows]);

  return (
    <CarouselWrapper>
      <Carousel
        slides={cards}
        currentSlide={goToSlide}
        offsetRadius={offsetRadius}
        showNavigation={showArrows}
        animationConfig={config.gentle}
      />
    </CarouselWrapper>
  );
}

export default Rotate;

const CarouselWrapper = styled.div`
  width: (${(props) => props.width});
  height: (${(props) => props.height});
  margin: (${(props) => props.margin});
`;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Rotate from "./props/Rotate";
import portfolioItems from "./data/portfolioItems";
import ImageMediaCard from "./ImageMediaCard";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

function Portfolio() {
  let cards = [
    {
      key: uuidv4(),
      content: <ImageMediaCard alt="1" />,
    },
    {
      key: uuidv4(),
      content: <ImageMediaCard alt="2" />,
    },
    {
      key: uuidv4(),
      content: <ImageMediaCard alt="3" />,
    },
    {
      key: uuidv4(),
      content: <ImageMediaCard alt="4" />,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <PortfolioWrapper id="portfolio">
      <PortfolioHeading>Portfolio</PortfolioHeading>
      <Rotate
        cards={
          {key: uuidv(),
            content: {portfolioItems.map((portfolioItem) => (
          <ImageMediaCard
            key={portfolioItem.id}
            image={portfolioItem.image}
            alt={portfolioItem.alt}
            title={portfolioItem.title}
            description={portfolioItem.description}
            website={portfolioItem.website}
            source={portfolioItem.source}
          />
        ))}}}
        height="500px"
        width="80%"
        margin="10px"
        offset={2}
        showArrows={false}
      />

      
    </PortfolioWrapper>
  );
}

export default Portfolio;

const PortfolioWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 100vw;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 900px;
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    display: block;
    display: inline-block;
  }
`;

const PortfolioHeading = styled.h2`
  font-size: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const RowWrap = styled.div`
  padding-top: 20px;
`;
const Row = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
`;

const Cards = styled(Card)`
  /* display: flex; */
  /* justify-content: space-around; */
`;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!